# iPhone App Deployment in Xcode to someone elses phone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to deploy to another persons phone in Xcode?  I dont own a iPhone but I'd like to test an app I've been making on my friends phone.  I'd like to make sure that this wont be a hassle before I pay my $99.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There won't be any hassle.

Once you have your itunes account setup as a dev account (join the iOS developer program) you can setup your signing certificates (easy) and then create a provisioning profile with your the UDID of your friends device.  Then it's just a matter of using the xcode organizer (or manually) to create an ipa file of your app that you can send by email.  You might also want to check out http://www.testflightapp.com.  The service is free and makes sending builds even easier since your friend will be able to install the build without iTunes.

Comment: +1 for TestFlight.  Works wonderfully in my testing experience.

Comment: another +1 for TestFlight, it's a fantastic service.

Answer (score 1):

You can add up to 100 devices to your developer account, you just need the serial number of the device, then you can add the device from the dev center in apples' web site. Then just download the file and drag it to Xcode and it will ad it to the device.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the application isn't signed. Download ldid from Cydia and then use it like so: ldid -S /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph

Also be sure that the binary is marked as executable: chmod +x /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph

Or you might be downloading it for the first time, to do so, you need to let the iPhone recognized by iTune .